# I don't understand Password={0} in a DbConnectionString

Tags: connection-string

I need to transfer a program from one old server to another newer to keep the program alive for a few months.
But it won't start.
In the Program.exe.config.deploy I found the code:

```
<setting name="DbConnectionString" serializeAs="String">
        <value>Data Source=SERVER1\KLIU;Initial Catalog=ProgramDB;User Id=UserDev;Password={0}</value>
      </setting>
```

But what does that password={0} do ?

I read in the comments things like "may", "it looks like" , so nobody really knows what it exactly is used for?

I am not a programmer, but can find my way in it. But what is a .deploy file, can you just change the data in it so the program reads it, or does it need to be re-build?

I tried to change the data in the file, but then the HASH gets changed...(aargh) And there is a program.manifest file that holds something like:

```
<file name="PROGRAM.exe.config" size="1978">
<hash>
  <dsig:Transforms>
    <dsig:Transform Algorithm="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:HashTransforms.Identity" />
  </dsig:Transforms>
  <dsig:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha256" />
  <dsig:DigestValue>hlIAj4I6J/Gxoe/G3FYl6Lc+fo=</dsig:DigestValue>
</hash>
```

But when I change the DigestValue in here and save it, the program cannot find the manifest file anymore as probrably this hash is changed to.... driving me crazy.

And I don't have the original .sln file so....

Comment: Looks like some kind of formatting code, so that `{0}` is replaced by the program with the actual password. I'm ***guessing***.

Answer (score 1):

The password may be unknown to the program that generated this line, and you need to write your database password.

Another options is that the connections string need to be parsed by another code, and be formatted when the password in known.